# rc-tree to display only folders not files

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/react-component/tree

- Expecting Tree view to work same as side navigation in Windows Explorer.
- Tree view to display only folders, not the files.
- onSelect a folder in Tree view, event handler shall display the
  sub-folders(cached) and files(API call) on the right side.

I am trying the provided http://react-component.github.io/tree/examples, but could not find an option to disable files(leafs) on the tree view

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tree, { TreeNode } from 'rc-tree';
import 'rc-tree/assets/index.css';
import './basic.less';

const treeData = [
  { key: '0-0', title: 'parent 1', children:
    [
      { key: '0-0-0', title: 'parent 1-1', children:
        [
          { key: '0-0-0-0', title: 'parent 1-1-0' },
        ],
      },
      { key: '0-0-1', title: 'parent 1-2', children:
          [
            { key: '0-0-1-0', title: 'parent 1-2-0', disableCheckbox: true },
            { key: '0-0-1-1', title: 'parent 1-2-1' },
          ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    keys: PropTypes.array,
  };
  static defaultProps = {
    keys: ['0-0-0-0'],
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const keys = props.keys;
    this.state = {
      defaultExpandedKeys: keys,
      defaultSelectedKeys: keys,
      defaultCheckedKeys: keys,
    };
  }
  onExpand = (...args) => {
    console.log('onExpand', ...args);
  };
  onSelect = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    console.log('selected', selectedKeys, info);
    this.selKey = info.node.props.eventKey;

    if (this.tree) {
      console.log(
        'Selected DOM node:',
        selectedKeys.map(key => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.tree.domTreeNodes[key])),
      );
    }
  };
  onCheck = (checkedKeys, info) => {
    console.log('onCheck', checkedKeys, info);
  };
  onEdit = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('current key: ', this.selKey);
    }, 0);
  };
  onDel = (e) => {
    if (!window.confirm('sure to delete?')) {
      return;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
  setTreeRef = (tree) => {
    this.tree = tree;
  };
  render() {
    const customLabel = (
      <span className="cus-label">
        <span>operations: </span>
        <span style={{ color: 'blue' }} onClick={this.onEdit}>Edit</span>&nbsp;
        <label onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
          <input type="checkbox" /> checked
        </label>
        &nbsp;
        <span style={{ color: '#EB0000' }} onClick={this.onDel}>Delete</span>
      </span>
    );

    return (
      <div style={{ margin: '0 20px' }}>
        <h2>simple</h2>
        <Tree
          ref={this.setTreeRef}
          className="myCls" showLine checkable defaultExpandAll
          defaultExpandedKeys={this.state.defaultExpandedKeys}
          onExpand={this.onExpand}
          defaultSelectedKeys={this.state.defaultSelectedKeys}
          defaultCheckedKeys={this.state.defaultCheckedKeys}
          onSelect={this.onSelect} onCheck={this.onCheck}
        >
          <TreeNode title="parent 1" key="0-0">
            <TreeNode title={customLabel} key="0-0-0">
              <TreeNode title="leaf" key="0-0-0-0" style={{ background: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)' }} />
              <TreeNode title="leaf" key="0-0-0-1" />
            </TreeNode>
            <TreeNode title="parent 1-1" key="0-0-1">
              <TreeNode title="parent 1-1-0" key="0-0-1-0" disableCheckbox />
              <TreeNode title="parent 1-1-1" key="0-0-1-1" />
            </TreeNode>
            <TreeNode title="parent 1-2" key="0-0-2" disabled>
              <TreeNode title="parent 1-2-0" key="0-0-2-0" checkable={false} />
              <TreeNode title="parent 1-2-1" key="0-0-2-1" />
            </TreeNode>
          </TreeNode>
        </Tree>

        <h2>Check on Click TreeNode</h2>
        <Tree
          className="myCls"
          showLine
          checkable
          selectable={ false }
          defaultExpandAll
          onExpand={this.onExpand}
          defaultSelectedKeys={this.state.defaultSelectedKeys}
          defaultCheckedKeys={this.state.defaultCheckedKeys}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          onCheck={this.onCheck}
          treeData={treeData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('__react-content'));
```

Show only the folder icons, not the files

Answer (score 0):

You can add prop isLeaf={false}

```
<TreeNode title="leaf" key="0-0-0-1" />
```